# Logstash everytime throws _grokparsefailure

Tags: logstash, grok

I have most recent **logstash** installed (2.3), and I want to parse *syslog* using grok filter.
So, here is the filter:

```
    filter {
  if [type] == "linux-syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "^%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp}\s*%{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname}\s*(%{PROG:syslog_program})?\s*(:?\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?:?\s*%{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}[a-z]*\s*$" }
      patterns_dir => ["/var/opt/logstash/patterns"]
      add_tag => "syslog_everything"
      keep_empty_captures => "true"
    }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
}
```

1. This is what I get from *logstash* trying to parse it:

   ```
            "message" => "Apr 20 14:31:35 node1 ansible-service: Invoked with name=logstash pattern=None enabled=True state=restarted sleep=None arguments= runlevel=default ",
           "@version" => "1",
         "@timestamp" => "2016-04-20T14:31:35.000Z",
               "path" => "/var/log/syslog",
               "host" => "node1",
               "type" => "linux-syslog",
   "syslog_timestamp" => "Apr 20 14:31:35",
    "syslog_hostname" => "node1",
     "syslog_program" => "ansible-service:",
         "syslog_pid" => nil,
     "syslog_message" => "Invoked with name=logstash pattern=None enabled=True state=restarted sleep=None arguments= runlevel=default ",
               "tags" => [
       [0] "syslog_everything",
       [1] "_grokparsefailure"
   ]
   ```

   }
2. And...

   {
                "message" => "Apr 20 14:35:10 node1 crontab[29052]: (vagrant) END EDIT (vagrant)",
               "@version" => "1",
             "@timestamp" => "2016-04-20T14:35:10.000Z",
                   "path" => "/var/log/syslog",
                   "host" => "node1",
                   "type" => "linux-syslog",
       "syslog_timestamp" => "Apr 20 14:35:10",
        "syslog_hostname" => "node1",
         "syslog_program" => "crontab",
             "syslog_pid" => "29052",
         "syslog_message" => "(vagrant) END EDIT (vagrant)",
                   "tags" => [
           [0] "syslog_everything",
           [1] "_grokparsefailure"
       ]
   }

---

What am I doing wrong here? I checked this using *grokdebugger* and it passed fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the fields are being created, then the grok is working.  You probably have another grok stanza that is failing.  Add a distinct tag_on_failure to each one.

Comment: Thanks, adding tag_on_failure to all my filters helped to find failing one. I didn't know that [tags] was one namespace common to all filters, thought it was just a field for one filter declaration.